# Outlet collection for UISwich

Tags: swift, uiswitch, iboutletcollection

I'm trying to create outlet collection for UISwitch but is seems to be not supported in XCode 9. I can do it for UITextField why not for UISwitch? I mean in Iterface Builder by drag&drop referencing.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ooops.. just found the way - drag&drop works from the code to storyboard but not in opposite way interestingly.